# Is there a simple override method to change the background of a webpart? SP 2010

Tags: web-part, sharepoint-designer, data-view-web-part, branding, content-editor-web-part

Found out how to change the background of one single page (body of that page). This works when I want a single page or two to have a specific background instead of modifying a master page.

Is there something similar to change the background color of a webpart? or add an image as the background? or even make it transparent?

Thanks as always!

Comment: I have been looking for this for a long time. thanks.
Is there any way to replace the background color with an image?
thanks again,
TDR.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically, it can be done with css with header and table changing:

```
.s4-wpTopTable {
background: 
#FEE;
}

.ms-WPHeader {
background: 
#FEE;
}
```

If you want to apply this to particular web-part, you can add additional css-marker class on you web-part render methods to find you web part instance later or use js/jQuery-client bases techniques to apply/change css on target webpart.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The WebPart class has properties for background color and background image URL.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webparts.webpart_properties

Comment: @rob...thanks for the reference. btw I have learned quite a lot from your videos out there! great help...thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can change the background by simply assigning relevant CSS to the topmost table or div tag that your webpart generates.For data-view, the html markup is in its XSL.